# Unable to close cmd console automatically after excution from java

Tags: java

I'm creating batch file using java and Running the same..
It creates successfully and runs as well..
But after execution , the window cmd prompt doesn't close ..
And if i using 
`taskkill /f /im cmd.exe`
it doesn't allow the complete execution.

How to close the cmd once the execution is completed..??
Any Help would be appreciated...

```
Runtime rt= Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd /c start "+serverPath+"SCA_"+projComp.getModule()+"_"+projComp.getProjectName()+"_"+projComp.getInside().get(i).getRuleSetName()+".bat", null, new File(serverPath+"MES/SERVER/MOS-ACI"));
```

Comment: Instead of starting `cmd`, just run your `bat` script.

Comment: You should execute the batch file directly and not call the command prompt

Comment: I think you could also save the return value of rt.exec(..) in a variable (type is Process) and then call the destroy() method

Comment: Simply running doesn't close the prompt..
some of them still runs in the background..

Answer (score 1):

You can create your bat file like that:

```
@echo off
cd //my command
exit
```

So you can execute your bat file like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "start Path-to-your-bat-file\\commandBAT.bat");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception = " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: if my solution work with you, thank you to validate my answer